# Session Management in extsj4

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, extjs, extjs4

What is the best way of implementing session, I am thinking at server side managing sessions like creation, validity of session based on that will be responding to Extjs4 client, Is it best way ?

In app.js I have used launch config as :

```
launch: function(){
    Ext.create('Myapp.view.LoginForm')
}
```

LoginForm : will show log in dialog and invoke log in controller for communicating with server for authenticating the credentials provided by the user.

So when ever user refreshes the page  Extjs is asking for log in that is because of I am not cheeking the session in here, How should be the session details stored in Extjs client and check to avoid prompting the log in unless user has log-out ? and How to manage user session ?

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the help of cookies and java script....